# Order by birthday, disregarding year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How do you make a query where you ORDER BY birthday disregarding the year altogether. I need to eliminate/disregard the year and ORDER BY birthdate month and birthdate day from today's date in either ASC or DESC.

The below won't work because the years of the birthdate come into play. The below example shows what happens when the year is regarded:

```
John   01/02/1974
Billy  11/15/2000
Ally   06/25/2008

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY birthdate
```

Expected results when ordering by birthday:

```
John   01/02/1974
Ally   06/25/2008
Billy  11/15/2000
```

Comment: In case you've already implemented the chosen solution, you should check the updated answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will normalize all dates to the year 2000:

```
ORDER BY DATEADD(YEAR, 2000-YEAR(birthday), birthday);
```

This will handle leap year babies correctly.

Comment: but what if there are dates older than 1900? :)

Comment: Now, I did!! :) just had to ask, though

Comment: This does work, but Andomar's solution disregards the year altogether by ordering by the day of the year. Thanks

Comment: @Patriotec ok... I think his solution may have challenges for leap year babies. I've corrected mine.

Comment: +1 for the leap year comment.  Doing date math right ain't easy!

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: @AaronBertrand's comment is correct, [day-of-year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) doesn't hold for leap years.  You could use his solution.  Another way is to order by month and day, like:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY month(birthdate), day(birthdate)
```

Comment: This is not enough on its own. Try dates `'2011-02-28','2011-03-01','2012-02-28','2012-02-29','2012-02-30'`... on my machine at least this puts `2011-03-01` before `2012-02-29`. Also I recommend spelling out the date part instead of using shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY SUBSTRING(birthdate, 1, 5);
```

Comment: This won't work if the column is a date/time data type, since it's not stored as the user presented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

It order the birthdate in ascending order

```
SELECT `id`, `teacher_name`, `phn_num`, `date_of_birth`, `date_of_birth` + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(`date_of_birth`)) + 0 YEAR AS currbirthday, `date_of_birth` + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(`date_of_birth`)) + 1 YEAR AS nextbirthday FROM `teacher_details` ORDER BY CASE WHEN currbirthday >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN currbirthday ELSE nextbirthday END
```